# How can I find my apple developer "Person ID"?

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

I want to find my "Person ID", and it seems that it is not in the developer center anymore. How can I locate this number?

Answer (score 1):

Your "Person ID" is the Apple ID that you used to sign up as a developer and that you use to submit apps for the Apple App Store.  You should find it in any emails you got from confirming your sign-up. Originally, your Apple ID could be any combination of characters, but Apple now requires that a new Apple ID be an actual email address.

Comment: I have a "Thank You for Joining the iOS Developer Enterprise Program" email, but it does not show me any Person ID, I was not sure, but I have been told that it should be a number.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: If it's all numbers, then I think you're you're talking about your Enrollment ID. It's possible it's not in your email. There should be an activation code or link in your email that takes you to a page at the Apple web site where you can see your Enrollment ID.

Comment: It's also possible your Developer enrollment has expired. Has it been a year since you enrolled?

Comment: nope, still enrolled.  Expiration Date: May 02, 2015.  Thanks for the help, looking in to enrollment ID now.

Comment: Did you find it and where ? I need it also.

Comment: @nycynik ,did you find a solution

Comment: No, I never found it.